# Show that $A$ is dense in $C_{\mathbb{R}}(K\times L)$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

Let $K, L$ be compact, metric spaces. Show that the algebra $A=C_{\mathbb{R}}(K)\otimes C_{\mathbb{R}}(L)=\{f(x)g(y)\mid f\in C_{\mathbb{R}}(K), g\in C_{\mathbb{R}}(L)\}$ is dense in $C_{\mathbb{R}}(K\times L)$.

---

My attempt:

I want to use Stone-Weierstrass theorem, so I need $3$ conditions.

1. $A$ is an algebra (question already says so)
2. $A$ separates points
3. $A$ contains the constant functions

For 3. I noticed that $C_{\mathbb{R}}(K)\ni f_1:K\rightarrow K$, $f_1(x)=1$ and $C_{\mathbb{R}}(L) \ni g_k:L\rightarrow L$, $g_k(y)=k$.
Then, for any constant function $C_{\mathbb{R}}(K\times L)\ni F(x,y) = k$ $\Rightarrow$ $F(x,y) = f_1(x)\cdot g_k(y) \in A$

For 2. I looked at $(x_1,y_1)$ and $(x_2,y_1)$ such that $(x_1,y_1)\neq (x_2,y_2)$. That means $x_1\neq x_2$ $\vee$ $y_1\neq y_2$.

Assuming $y_1\neq y_2$ then I think $\exists$ function $g\in C_{\mathbb{R}}(L)$ s.t

$$
g(y_1)\neq g(y_2)? \tag{*}
$$

If so, $F(x,y)=f_1(x)\cdot g(y)=g(y)$ $\Rightarrow$ $F(x_1,y_1)\neq F(x_2y_2)$. I can do the same for $x_1\neq x_2$

Is this correct? How can I explain $(*)$? Has this something to do with $L$ being separable?

Comment: Let $d_K$ and $d_L$ denote the metrics for $K$ an $L$. For $P_1=(x_1,y_1)$ and $P2:=(x_2,y_2)$ define the point separating function $F(.,..):=d_K(x_1,.)+d_L(y_1,..)$. Why is F member of the Algebra ?

Comment: @Maksim I don't really know honestly. But maybe my understanding of $C_{\mathbb{R}}(K)$ is a little bit flawed. Is it the space of all continuous functions from $K\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: It's the set of all continuous real valued functions, yes. If $d_K$ is the metric on $K$ then let us fix a $x_0 \in K$. Let us define $f:K \to \mathbb R$ by $f(t):=d_K(x_0,t)$ for all $ t \in K$. Is $f$ then a continuous ?